# How to make np.where more efficient with triangular matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-itertools

I got this code where distance is a lower triangular matrix defined as this:

```
distance = np.tril(scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(points, points))  
def make_them_touch(distance):
    """
    Return the every distance where two points touched each other. See example below.
    """
    thresholds = np.unique(distance)[1:] # to avoid 0 at the beginning, not taking a lot of time at all
    result = dict()
    for t in thresholds:
            x, y = np.where(distance == t)
            result[t] = [i for i in zip(x,y)]
    return result
```

My problem is that np.where is quite slow with big matrix (2000*100 for example).
How can I speed up this code, by improving np.where or by changing the algo ?

**EDIT :** as [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50907222/9453926) pointed out, the best optimization here is NOT to generate a squared matrix and to use iterators.

## Example :

```
points = np.array([                                                                        
...: [0,0,0,0],                                                            
...: [1,1,1,1],         
...: [3,3,3,3],              
...: [6,6,6,6]                             
...: ])  

In [106]: distance = np.tril(scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(points, points))

In [107]: distance
Out[107]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 6.,  4.,  0.,  0.],
   [12., 10.,  6.,  0.]])

In [108]: make_them_touch(distance)
Out[108]: 
{2.0: [(1, 0)],
 4.0: [(2, 1)],
 6.0: [(2, 0), (3, 2)],
 10.0: [(3, 1)],
 12.0: [(3, 0)]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE1:** here is a snippet for an *upper* triangular distance matrix (it shouldn't really matter as the distance matrix is always symmetric):

```
from itertools import combinations

res = {tup[0]:tup[1] for tup in zip(pdist(points), list(combinations(range(len(points)), 2)))}
```

result:

```
In [111]: res
Out[111]:
{1.4142135623730951: (0, 1),
 4.69041575982343: (0, 2),
 4.898979485566356: (1, 2)}
```

---

**UPDATE2:** this version will support duplicates in distances:

```
In [164]: import pandas as pd
```

first we construct a Pandas.Series:

```
In [165]: s = pd.Series(list(combinations(range(len(points)), 2)), index=pdist(points))

In [166]: s
Out[166]:
2.0     (0, 1)
6.0     (0, 2)
12.0    (0, 3)
4.0     (1, 2)
10.0    (1, 3)
6.0     (2, 3)
dtype: object
```

now we can group by index and produce lists of coordinates:

```
In [167]: s.groupby(s.index).apply(list)
Out[167]:
2.0             [(0, 1)]
4.0             [(1, 2)]
6.0     [(0, 2), (2, 3)]
10.0            [(1, 3)]
12.0            [(0, 3)]
dtype: object
```

PS the main idea here is that you shouldn't build square distance matrix if you are going to flatten it afterwards and to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: @politinsa, what are you trying to achieve? It's not very clear from your question.

Comment: Yout solution is very fast, thank you for your update ! I'm trying to get filtration/persistence of a [Rips Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietoris%E2%80%93Rips_complex). Here is a [Paper](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~ghrist/preprints/barcodes.pdf)

Comment: @politinsa, glad i could help :)

Comment: @politinsa, sure you can! I would appreciate if you would leave a link to this post as a comment in your code though ;-)

Comment: Already done ;) To comment about your answer, the drawback here is that if ones has many distances with the same value, the last one erase the previous one. But no matter what, even using a list is infinity faster than my function.

Comment: @politinsa, that's the nature of dictionary - it can't have duplicated keys. I could try to fix this if you would provide a reproducible sample data set

Comment: I've updated my question. I can do it myself but for the posterity of the answer, please feel free to improve yours.